# hbox provokes a bug when defining a new environment with tcolorbox

Tags: environments, tcolorbox

I want to make a new environment like this:

```
\newenvironment{smallbox}[1][black]{
\colorlet{ShadowColor}{#1!70!black}\vspace{10px}
\begin{center}
\begin{tcolorbox}[hbox,valign=center,colback=#1!5!white, colframe=#1!80!black, enhanced jigsaw,sharp corners, drop shadow=ShadowColor]
}
{\end{tcolorbox}
\end{center}
\vspace{10px}
}
```

When I put it in a .sty file and use the .sty file as a package in a new .tex and then uses the smallbox environment, I get the following error:

```
\begin{tcolorbox} on input line 154 ended by \end{smallbox}
```

If I remove the argument hbox in tcolorbox from the .sty file, the .tex compiles.

If I try to write directly in the .tex file,

```
\begin{tcolorbox}[hbox,valign=center,colback=#1!5!white, colframe=#1!80!black, enhanced jigsaw,sharp corners, drop shadow=ShadowColor]
%stuff    
\end{tcolorbox}
```

this also works. So there's a problem with defining a newenvironment with hbox passed as an argument to tcolorbox.

Any ideas?

Comment: `tcolorbox` scans for the end statement without processing, so you can't do that. There is a `\newtcolorbox` (or similar) for this...

Comment: please provide a test file that shows the problem, it is much harder to guess how to test disconnected fragments.

Comment: you say if you use `\begin{tcolorbox}[hbox,valign=center,colback=#1!5!white` directly it works, but doesn't that generate errors from the `#1` if not in a definition?

Comment: @Rmano solution works. Yes I replaced #1 with white when not using the newenvironment.